# How many copies of unique items, distributed evenly to $m$ people, are required such that any group of $r$ people has each type

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

So, I have a combinatorics problem that I have partially solved but I need a little help finishing.

The problem goes like this:

There are $M$ people and $R$ of them are required to open a safe with multiple locks. You must find a way to **evenly** distribute, to $M$ people, the keys to these locks such that any group of $R$ people has each key but no group of $R-1$ does.

The first part of the problem requires knowing the minimum number of keys. This is a common combinatorics problem that has been asked and answered previously on this forum. 
The solution is $n_{keys} = {M \choose R-1}$

The second part of the problem entails figuring out how many copies of the keys are required to be able to **evenly** distribute the keys while still ensuring that no group of $R-1$ can open the safe.

For example:
When  $M = 4$, $R = 2$, $n_{keys} = 4$. 
But it is impossible to distribute just 4 keys to the 4 people while ensuring any 2 of them have all 4 keys. The only way is to make 3 copies of the keys. and distribute them [0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3],[1,2,3].

Can anyone help me work out a general solution for the number of copies required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem myself by trial and error with the help of some code.

The solution is:
$n_{copies}=M−(R−1)$.

Comment: You can see it because there can be only $R-1$ people lacking each key.  If there were $R$, the set of people without that key could not open the safe.  This does not prove that this is enough.  It could be that for some $M,R$ you need more keys than this